# Magento 2 graphql integration with Hosted(Redirect) Payment method

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, payment, payment-gateway, graphql

i want to create graphql api for custom Hosted(Redirect) payment method.

can anyone elaborate step how can i create that for payment method?

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: yes, need to create 2 diffrent mutation, 1) for getting redirect URL 2) for success transaction

Comment: Do you have a sample module that you can share with me please

Comment: @JigsParmar Brother, how you  implemented this? Can you please share your solution here? this would be very helpful for us